# Wordpress keep logged in after browser close

Tags: cookies, session

I want my users to be logged in even after they close the browser. I have tried below code but nothing happens, it still logging me out after closing the browser.

```
function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year( $expirein ) {
return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
```

How will I keep my users logged in even after they close the browser?

Comment: Try this: add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', function(){
    return YEAR_IN_SECONDS * 2;
});

Comment: Thanks... its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following 2 filter hooks

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'auth_cookie_expiration_filter_5587');
function auth_cookie_expiration_filter_5587()
{
    return YEAR_IN_SECONDS * 5;
}
```

and:

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', function () {
    return YEAR_IN_SECONDS * 5;
});
```

Comment: This is not working for me. No matter what I do, when I close the browser I'm logged out. How do I get the cookie to not just be a session cookie if I don't click "remember me"?